# Symfony 6.1 Tried to make live - having endless problems

Tags: php, symfony

I have a site which I've converted to Symfony 6.1 starting from a blank site and copying stuff over from the previous 3.4 site. In dev, everything works perfectly.

Today, I've tried to make it live. I deleted all previous content, cloned my repo and updated to latest version. I created a .env.prod.local file and set the APP_ENV variable to prod from dev.

Symfony is simply not detecting the change of environment. In my folder I have the .env file which is the default, I have not made any changes in that file. In my dev environment, I have .env.dev.local, I changed this to .env.prod.local in my production environment and updated the DB connection string and APP_ENV variable. The resulting errors showed that the env vars were not being picked up. After some research, I ran `composer dump-env prod` and that produced a .env.local.php file with the same vars as .env.prod.local. However, if I run   `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` it says `No environment variables are being used.`. If I edit the .env.local.php file and change APP_ENV from 'prod' to 'dev', save and close, and run `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` again, then I see the vars I am expecting to see.

I cannot run my site in dev mode since it shows the development profiler and this cannot be visible. I cannot run the site in prod since it fails to pickup the vars from the .env.local.php file ***sometimes*** - some pages work while others throw a 500 internal server error. On the pages that throw a 500 error, if I change APP_ENV back to dev and load the page again, there is no error and no problems shown in the profiler. I have no information about what the error is in prod mode, I just see a generic error message and there are no logs or error messages on the server that I can find.

I'm running on Apache 2.4 and PHP 8.1.

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some random and desperate testing, I changed the APP_ENV var to 'live', and this allowed me to see the full error message (instead of a generic `500 internal server error` message), and that message showed me that I was missing a /config/services_prod.yaml file. I created this file and cleared the cache, and no more error! Also, setting APP_ENV to live does not show the profiler bar, which was better than setting APP_ENV to dev in an actual production environment and having end users seeing the profiler bar...

All in all a massive PITA, setting this site live should have been an easy process and it's ended up costing me 4 hours just because of having no idea what Symfony is doing with environment variables (despite reading the docs like 5 times). I still don't understand why running `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` with APP_ENV as `prod` shows `No environment variables are being used.`, while setting APP_ENV to `dev` or `live` and running `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` shows the expected vars. Seems to be a problem with Symfony?

Comment: Did you adjust src/Kernel::configureContainer() by any chance?  Out of the box Symfony loads `config/services.yaml` as well as `config/services_$env.yaml` but it does not throw an error when the file is missing.  Maybe a permissions thing?  Seems unlikely.  If you are so inclined try to duplicate the problem by creating a new 6.1 app, add one controller and then push to your prod server and see what happens.  If the same problem happens then an issue could be opened.  Or there might even be one now.

Comment: First thing you should do is to make sure your logs work when errors happen. Without this you will not know what is happening on production. Create some controller with action and put there intentionally some error - like run not existing function: `i_dont_exist();`. Then try to execute this action on local, make sure log about this error is saved in file. Then repeat on production. If it doesnt save logs then probably you will need to tweak your logs configuration (Monolog etc) https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html

Comment: There may be also problem with server configuration (directory write permissions etc).

Comment: @Cerad no I didn't adjust `src/Kernel::configureContainer()` - there was no permissions problem, just the missing `services_$env.yaml' file - creating that file fixed it.

Comment: @domis86 yes I agree, logging wasn't working on live and I didn't know why - I don't usually develop with Symfony, this is a legacy site I have to look after. I've just been and chased that up and got live logging to file working.

Comment: @domis86 all file permissions are identical, I regularly reset them to avoid permissions problems after pulling from external repo etc.

Comment: @Ben When you get a chance grep your project's code for `services_prod.yaml`.  I'm quite confident that Symfony itself does not require this file to exist.  I suspect it might be in one of the files you copied/edited from your original 3.4 code.

Comment: @Cerad `services_prod.yaml` does not exist for sure, that's why I was getting the error. Once I switched APP_ENV to 'live' then I saw the error looking for an environment variable that I then knew is in services_dev.yaml. Symfony was erroring when it looked for that environment variable. I don't think there is any mystery left around `services_prod|live.yaml`, and for sure it would have been easier had I already configured prod logging, however I hadn't and prod logging goes to stderr by default and in the moment I was stressed because I couldn't get the site live and so didn't look at logging

Comment: @Cerad the only really mystery remaining is why Symfony says `No environment variables are being used` when running `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` with APP_ENV set to prod. This is really weird, literally any other value for APP_ENV works fine, but for prod it refuses to read the `.env.local.php` file.

Comment: @Ben any funky stuff in you `bin/console` file? Do you tried to align/compare your project to official boilerplate https://github.com/symfony/demo ?  Do you tried debug commands listed here? https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#listing-environment-variables  .

Comment: @Ben I realize that I was not clear in my previous comment.  What I meant was to search for the string `services_prod.yaml` just to see if it was being included by any other of your configuration files.  I still think it would be worthwhile for you to push a newly created and very simple 6.x app to your server just to see what happens.  You may end up getting your legacy app working now but it might be difficult to maintain going forward without sorting this stuff out.

Comment: @Cerad & @domis86 this is literally a brand new, out of the box 6.1 site, to which I transferred the old controllers, entities and templates by hand. I did not touch any of Symfony's own files, definitely not `bin/console`. @Cerad I don't understand why you want me to grep for services_prod.yaml, I had the problem that I had created services_dev.yaml and when I deployed to prod I forgot this file existed and did not create services_prod.yaml, since prod doesn't show errors in the browser and I didn't have prod logging setup, I did not have any info about the error, but that was 100% my fault.

Comment: @Cerad the only unexplained problem is that Symfony says `No environment variables are being used` when running `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` with APP_ENV set to prod. That has nothing to do with services_prod.yaml existing or not. I have parameters in the services_$env.yaml file as per https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration.

Comment: @Ben `only unexplained problem is that Symfony says No environment variables are being used` - maybe it is this problem? : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32655#issuecomment-513813011  . The mentioned "debug" is second argument here: https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/main/bin/console#L14